# How can I catch if an xml node does not exist in xml using linq to xml in c#?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

My problem is that in data of my xml sometimes a specific node does not exists how can I catch that to avoid `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error` and just skip that value and continue adding items in listview?

Here is the query of my linq to xml

```
var summary = from r in doc.Descendants("TrxDetailCard") 
                      select new 
                      {
                          Account_Type = r.Element("Account_Type_CH").Value,
                          Captured = r.Element("Captured").Value,
                          Trans_Type_ID = r.Element("Trans_Type_ID").Value,
                          Acct_Num_CH = r.Element("Acct_Num_CH").Value,
                          Tip_Amt_MN = r.Element("Tip_Amt_MN").Value,
                          Total_Amt_MN = r.Element("Total_Amt_MN").Value,
                          Date_DT = r.Element("Date_DT").Value,
                      };
```

The `Tip_Amt_MN` sometimes does not exists

Add items in listview

```
foreach (var i in summary)
        {
            ListViewItem it = new ListViewItem(i.Account_Type.ToString());
            it.SubItems.Add(i.Captured.ToString());
            it.SubItems.Add(i.Trans_Type_ID.ToString());
            it.SubItems.Add(i.Acct_Num_CH.ToString());
            it.SubItems.Add(i.Tip_Amt_MN.ToString());
            it.SubItems.Add(i.Total_Amt_MN.ToString());
            it.SubItems.Add(i.Date_DT.ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(it);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the property being set to null, then you can cast the XElement to string.  In other words, this won't throw an exception if the `Account_Type_CH` element doesn't exist:

```
Account_Type = (string)r.Element("Account_Type_CH")
```

Comment: @GrayFullBuster casting to string gets the inner content of the node -- same as `.Value`, but it won't throw.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to make liberal use of FirstOrDefault() in situations where I don't want to break a query up:

```
r.Element("Tip_Amt_MN").Value
```

becomes:

```
r.Elements("Tip_Amt_MN").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault()
```